# JavaScript queryselector method not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, ie8-compatibility-mode

Following code is working in Chrome but not working in IE

```
repNumObject    = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked");
```

It is throwing error of invalid argument in try catch block
please suggest solution

Comment: does your page have  a proper DOCTYPE declaration?

Comment: IE8 only has partial support (http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), but you should probably drop IE8 support, as Windows XP is officially dead, and IE8 lies next to it.

Comment: @DasDas it has proper DTD and works in Chrome and IE 9+, I needed it to work in IE8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the [:checked selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked), which is [not supported in IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked#Browser_compatibility)

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
//need to loop els and find the checked item
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].checked) {
        repNumObject = els[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help it worked for all browsers, this is exact answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector in IE8 only recognized CSS 2.1 selectors and non special tags (html5 tags like section or article).
To avoid this asap, you could use some library like jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Comment: It is true but I cannot use JQ because of platform it is being deployed